# leer y parsear un archivo txt grande en C++

Tags: c++, archivo

Tengo un archivo de texto de aproximadamente de **14k lineas**.

Tiene este tipo de formato

```
&
Apple_01.png
Momentos_Hu:
0.166941
0.000099
0.000077
0.000007
-0.000000
-0.000000
-0.000000
Descriptores_de_Fourier:
88416.051043
837.762710
1396.600494
3180.998153
1519.174257
982.949974
1076.461889
803.433229
361.719247
48.874787
364.442782
289.045564
287.944762
249.049309
266.845083
176.641688
141.699516
221.873393
190.489906
225.442040
167.384044
578.495958
491.386066
125.524673
574.019210
117.239230
135.196151
225.674568
439.043996
1400.427781
341.615659
1850.483871
1677.123852
402.668641
2416.109125
43343.467325
&
```

Lo que tengo que hacer es leer el archivo, tomar los valores numéricos de momentos Hu y de descriptores de Fourier para luego compararlos. No consigo cargar los datos cuando ejecuto mi programa, ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Podrias compartir en codigo el avance que tienes para que sea más facil entender la pregunta

Comment: "*¿alguna idea?*" La verdad es que no. No tengo ni idea de qué es lo que falla en el código que no has mostrado.

Comment: Creo que si muestras tu código podemos ayudarte mejor. Cuanta más información proporciones, más posibilidades de que encontramos dónde está el problema ¿no crees? :)